# dispatchEvent() with a function as param, executes the function instead of passing it

Tags: javascript, events, listener

I'm trying to dispatch an event to window.top.document as

code in frame1:

```
function callingBell(){
    alert('ding dong');
}

 var event = window.top.document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
 event.initCustomEvent('READY', false, false, { 'bell': callingBell });
 window.top.document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

in frame2:

```
window.top.document.addEventListener('BOMREADY', function(e) {

    bell= e.detail.bell;

}, false);
```

More Details: 
I have a parent jsp. Within the parent jsp, I have 2 child jsps. The scenario works well the first time. When I refresh/reload the two child jsps while the parent frame is not refreshed- the above issue occurs. The number of times the alert "ding dong" is displayed is exactly the number of times I refresh the child frames.
Meaning: on the 7th refresh, the alert appears 7 times. I suspect something in the window.top.document is currupted to execute the function before passing it to the listener.

On second refresh onwards, when execution reaches "window.top.document.dispatchEvent(event)", instead of getting into the target listener first, the callingBell function is called and the alert is displayed before the execution reaches the listener code.

Also, if callingBell is not a function, the listener is called once, as expected.

UPDATE: 
I can solve this problem by simply removing the event listener inside the addEventListener using:

```
  e.target.removeEventListener('READY', arguments.callee, false);
```

but, I can't do this as a final solution as I need the listener for a later event.

Comment: Wich browser do you use?

Comment: Chrome... This is reproducible in all browsers

Comment: The repeat is because it's being added each time the child is refreshed. If you make the callback a named function, you can always remove the listener first before adding it.

Comment: Thank you so much...That works. Please post this as an answer. So I can give the bounty. As you can see this has been open for a month.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you get this issue because you do not remove the listener on your callback. This is why each time you actually refresh you stack your events and get multiples alerts.

This is how I would actually make this :

```
window.top.document.addEventListener('BOMREADY', _callback(e), false);

function _callback(e) {
  window.top.document.removeEventListener('BOMREADY', _callback(e), false);

  // Keep executing your function
  bell = e.detail.bell;
  bell();
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: I have mentioned in my post that it works when I remove the event. But I can't remove the listener because I need it for some other purpose.